JLPT3 Question: why is 差し上げる wrong in this case?
I got this question from JLPT3 listening comprehension:

Question:
先生がたくさん荷物を持っています。何といいますか

先生、お持ちしましょうか
先生、持って差し上げますか
先生、持ってもらいたいですか

The correct answer is 1. However, I don't really understand why 2 is wrong, since according to tofugu (https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/kureru-ageru-morau/) 差し上げる is the more humble version of あげる which can be used to give something someone in higher position?

お客様にお手紙を差し上げる。
I give a letter to my client.

I guess Number 3 is incorrect because you don't use たい　for expressing or talking about other peoples whishes/aspirations (instead use がる)
update: here is how deepl translates it:

Sir, can I take it for you?

Sir, can I hold it for you?

Doctor, would you like to have it?


Seems like I'm missing something.
Thanks :)

For what it's worth, it's perfectly fine to use “〜たい” when asking what someone wants, or even using it with say “〜だろう” or “多分” in a sentence or anything that expresses some degree of uncertainty. The third one is wrong because it doesn't make much sense to ask whether someone wants to receive something with nothing else but I'm not sure why 2 is incorrect either and I'd love to know.

Maybe 2 is wrong, maybe it is not, but also keep in mind that in multiple clause questions for JLPT, typically, the requirement is not to choose the only right answer, but to choose the most appropriate answer or the answer that fits best. In other words, it might be the case that neither 1 nor 2 are wrong, but 1 is more natural than 2.

If I had to guess, I'd say that 2 not being the correct answer has something to do with using やる/あげる/差し上げる inside a question.

Isn't 2 approximately "Will I carry it for you?"? In English at least, that sounds quite strange.

@Zorf ah yeah you’re right, using tai is ok for asking questions. regarding answer 3, I just forgot to add the 持って - I updated the question

@Kaskade could be yes, deepl translates it differently however, but who knows, deepl always tries to make somehow sense of what you write even if it doesn’t

@Kaskade “Shall I carry this for you?” is fine though but you're right and I actually misread what it said as “差し上げましょうか？” You cannot use a simple future for yourself like this in Japanese to ask things but you can for others “食べる？” for “Wanna eat it?” is fine but it can't be used to mean “Shall I eat this?”

@Zorf yeah now I see, so 差し上げましょうか would be ok too? I guess that answers the question, actually makes sense, I don’t know why I didn‘t saw that lol

so 差し上げましょうか would be ok too?  It sounds very patronizing.

I think that even if choice n.2 is gramatically correct, it sounds odd when applied to honorific speech. The use of benefactive on behalf of a superior asks for some caution, to prevent risks of patronizing or of looking presumptous. In this case one is asking the teacher if he is to do him a favor, which is kind of paradox even if one uses the humble "sashiageru"

@Zorf "You cannot use a simple future for yourself like this in Japanese to ask things" Actually, you can. This question has been asked here a few times.

@desmo, so you mean that say “手伝う？” for instance is correct for “Shall I help you?”, to offer help?

I suspect it's for the same reason that one generally doesn't use あげる in these situations.
To borrow an explanation from Senko K. Maynard's "An Introduction to Japanese Grammar and Communication Strategies":

Because of the implication of personal interest, special care is required when using [Verb て-form]+あげる expressions. When used in a question like これ買ってあげましょうか, the listener may resent it. This expression gives an impression that since the listener is helpless and is perhaps incapable of performing the action, he or she must receive charity from the other. A thoughtful Japanese will use これ買いましょうか instead.


+1. If we remove the keigo from the second option and say "持ってあげようか?" to your friend, it would sound somewhat inconsiderate to me.

Should "持とうか?" be more appropriate instead of "持ってあげようか?"
